# Post value for dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have register.php. When the person submit the form, the value will post and insert into database. I have username, email, country, password to be inserted into database.

My country is in dropdown.

This is something I've done that worked.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" 
  placeholder="Username" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['username'])) { echo $_POST['username']; } ?>" required autofocus>
</div>
```

Now I have this country dropdown. The country will be stored in string like "Australia".

```
<div class="form-group ui selection dropdown ">
      <input type="hidden" name="country" class="form-control"> 
      <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
      <div class="default text">Select a country</div>
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="item" data-value="af"><i class="af flag"></i>Afghanistan</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="ax"><i class="ax flag"></i>Aland Islands</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="al"><i class="al flag"></i>Albania</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="dz"><i class="dz flag"></i>Algeria</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="as"><i class="as flag"></i>American Samoa</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="ad"><i class="ad flag"></i>Andorra</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="ao"><i class="ao flag"></i>Angola</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="ai"><i class="ai flag"></i>Anguilla</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="ag"><i class="ag flag"></i>Antigua</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="ar"><i class="ar flag"></i>Argentina</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="am"><i class="am flag"></i>Armenia</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="aw"><i class="aw flag"></i>Aruba</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="au"><i class="au flag"></i>Australia</div>
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
```

How do I set the initial value of the dropdown from a _POST variable if one is set?

edited

```
<select name="gender" class="form-group ui selection dropdown" id="select">
      <option value="">Select a country</option>
      <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
      <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
      <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
      <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
      <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
      ...
</select>
```

Comment: When you select or change the value in dropdown, does the hidden input get updated or not? Also, tell your bootstrap version.

Comment: Use a `<select>` with `<option>`s and a `<label>` not a `<div>` with `<div>`s and `<div>`!

Comment: Use a `<select>` element.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman im not sure whether the hidden input is updated, how do i know? I'm using semantic ui

Comment: @PixelThings Where did you get such a code? You should really be using `<select>`... Got confused seeing the `form-group` class.

Comment: @Quentin got it, but the css is pretty sensitive, i kind of dont want to get my hands on them

Comment: They are asking you to change the HTML, not the CSS.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman it was always like that from the documentation. I'll try the <select>

Comment: @PixelThings Will have a look at it once... Give me some time.

Comment: @PixelThings Yea, right. Looks fine to me. Did you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman im switching the div to select, will update

Comment: You don't need to switch from div to select. From your code, I suspect you are using a javaScript library and accompanying css, share them with us.

Comment: +1 for you don't need to switch to select, looks like you have some UI javascript / css framework going on their and some javascript would be required but first you will need to share the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the initial value specify selected attribute to the appropriate option like this:

```
<?php

     $gender = $_POST['gender']; //get value from post

?>

<select name="gender" class="form-group ui selection dropdown" id="select">
      <option value="">Select a country</option>
      <option value="Afghanistan" <?= ($gender=="Afghanistan"?"selected":"") ?>>Afghanistan</option>
      <option value="Albania" <?= ($gender=="Albania"?"selected":"") ?>>Albania</option>
      <option value="Algeria" <?= ($gender=="Algeria"?"selected":"") ?>>Algeria</option>
      <option value="American Samoa" <?= ($gender=="American Samoa"?"selected":"") ?>>American Samoa</option>
      <option value="Andorra" <?= ($gender=="Andorra"?"selected":"") ?>>Andorra</option>
      ...

</select>
```